# Merge two dictionaries in Jinja2

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2

I have some code which basically searches some YAML files for Jinja2 variables and replaces them where appropriate. I want to be able to combine to YAML dicts together and was looking for a way to do this using the default Jinja2 library.

Here is some example YAML of what I am trying to a achieve:

---

vars.yml

```yaml
vars:
  default:
    name: test1
    location: UK
  new:
    name: test2
    country: UK
```

---

template.yml

```yaml
test: {{ vars.default.update(vars.new) }}
```

---

This would ideally output something like:

output.yml

```yaml
test:
  name: test2
  location : UK
  country: UK
```

I am looking for a way to merge two dictionaries together using this method. [The Jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#builtin-filters) don't appear to have an inbuilt function like the Ansible [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter.

Is it possible that I just import this feature into my code or create a similar feature? I noticed that it is [not included in the standard library for Ansible Jinja2 filters](https://pypi.org/project/jinja2-ansible-filters/)

When trying to use the update filter (which doesn't appear to exist in the Jinja2 documentation) I get a `None` result.

Comment: `dict.update` is working as it should be with two dict, perhaps you share the final output you want

Comment: Hey, in the post, the output.yml shows what I want after the update.  Another user has told me why this was expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `update` method of a dictionary is actually updating the source dictionary, not returning the merged dictionaries.

> **update([*other*])**
> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from *other*, overwriting existing keys. Return `None`.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update*</sup>

So, you have two ways of achieving it:

- either you have [the expression-statement extension loaded](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/extensions/#expression-statement) and you can use the [`{% do ... %}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#expression-statement) construct:

  ```
  {% do vars.default.update(vars.new) -%}
  test: {{ vars.default }}
  ```
- or it is not activated and you can use a dummy assignation:

  ```
  {% set noop = vars.default.update(vars.new) -%}
  test: {{ vars.default }}
  ```

Comment: My Pycharm seems to flag an error when I do the {% -%}, presumably because this is not valid YAML. I have tried to add it as `test: {% do vars.default.update(vars.new) -%} {{ vars.default }}` but this has still returned `None` so likely not working as I expect it.

Comment: The fact that PyCharm flags it is a misconfiguration, nothing more, your IDE should understand that it is a Jinja file, that templates a YAML file.

Comment: No I've just tried to run it and no good.  The code I have is unhappy as it has an attribute weor with a NoneType object has no attribute get.  This is because part of my code is searching for a specific key on my YAML, and putting the {% -%} throws an error when the function which tries to find Jinja2 syntax runs.

Comment: @craigtho so, you are not at all templating with Jinja you have a whatever parser that try to do as if it was templating?

Comment: No Jinja2 is in there, filters that are being used and imported and used into the YAML.  Maybe my question was clear, I wanted a way to combine 2 dicts in YAML using a J2 filter, the ansible combine one did this.  I have written something similar and added it.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, `update` operates in place and doesn't return the updated dictionary.

A possible solution is based on the fact the YAML format has its own built in way to base one dictionary on another:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

path = Path('vars.yaml')
path.write_text("""\
vars:
  default: &base
    name: test1
    location: UK
  new:
    <<: *base
    name: test2
    country: UK
""")

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(path)
print(data['vars']['new'])
```

which gives:

```
{'name': 'test2', 'location': 'UK', 'country': 'UK'}
```

So if Ansible uses a standard YAML library that implements the [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), you can simply make your Jinja2 template:

```
test: {{ vars.new }}
```

, but this requires you to "specify" the merge in you YAML input and not in your Jinja2 file,
and that might not be an option.

Please note that the [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for files containing YAML
files has been  `.yaml` since at least September 2006.
There is also a [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format, which is XML based and at least as old as YAML,
so you should exclusively use `.yml` for that format.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by copying the combine function (or something like it) from the ansible libary.  Here is what I made.

my_filters.py

```py
def combine(*args):
    ret = {}
    for arg in args:
        if arg is None:
            continue
        if isinstance(arg, dict):
            ret.update(arg)
        else:
            raise ValueError("combine filter arguments must be dictionaries")
    return ret
```

When inside my code (I can't post all of it), I updated my library dependencies

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from my_filters import combine

"""
omitted stuff
"""
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
env.filters['combine'] = combine
yaml = env.from_string(yaml_file)
```